# Operator &~31 of C Program

Tags: c

I want to ask about C operator from this code. My friends ask it, but I never seen this operator:

```
binfo_out.biSizeImage = ( ( ( (binfo_out.biWidth * binfo_out.biBitCount) + 31) & ~31) / 8) * abs(out_bi.biHeight);
```

What this operator `& ~31` mean? anybody can explain this?

Comment: They are not one, but two bit manipulation operator, google for their usage.

Comment: some multiplication and addition, take that and bitwise "and" it with the bitwise "not" of 31.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `&` operator is a bitwise AND. The `~` operator is a bitwise NOT (i.e. inverts the bits). As 31 is binary `11111`, ~31 is binary `1111111....111100000` (i.e. a number which is all ones, but has five zeroes at the end). Anding a number with this thus clears the least significant five bits, which (if you think about it) rounds down to a multiple of 32.

What does the whole thing do? Note it adds 31 first. This has the effect that the whole thing rounds something UP to the next multiple of 32.

This might be used to calculate (for instance), how many bits are going to be used to store something if you can only use 32 bit quantities to store them, as there is going to be some wastage in the last 32 bit number.

Answer (score 3):

31 in binary representation will be 11111 so ~31 = 5 zeros 00000 preceeded by 1's. so it is to make last 5 bits zero. i.e. to mask the last 5 bits.
here ~ is NOT operator i.e. it gives 1's complement. and & is AND operator.

Answer (score 2):

`&` is the [bitwise AND operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17zwb64t.aspx). It *and's* every corresponding bit of two operands on its both sides. In an example, it does the following:

*Let `char` be a type of 8 bits.*

```
unsigned char a = 5;
unsigned char b = 12;
```

*Their bit representation would be as follows:*

```
a     --> 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 // 5
b     --> 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 // 12
```

*And the bitwise AND of those would be:*

```
a & b --> 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 // 8
```

Now, the `~` is the [bitwise NOT operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s50et82s.aspx), and it negates every single bit of the operand it prefixes. In an example, it does the following:

*With the same `a` from the previous example, the `~a` would be:*

```
~a    --> 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 // 250
```

Now with all this knowledge, `x & ~31` would be the bitwise AND of `x` and `~31`, where the bit representation of `~31` looks like this:

```
~31   --> 1111 1111   1111 1111   1111 1111   1110 0000 // -32 on my end
```

So the result would be whatever the `x` has on its bits, other than its last 5 bits.

Answer (score 0):

> & ~31

means `bitwise and` of the operand on the left of `&` and a `bitwise not` of `31`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Answer (score 0):

The number 31 in binary is `11111` and `~` in this case is the unare one's compliment operator. So assuming 4-byte `int`:

```
~31 = 11111111 11111111 11111111 11100000
```

The `&` is the bitwise AND operator. So you're taking the value of:

```
((out_bi.biWidth * out_bi.biBitCount) + 31)
```

And performing a bitwise AND with the above value, which is essentially blanking the 5 low-order bits of the left-hand result.